# Find time periods in .csv file with python

Tags: python, csv, statistics

## Summary

I have a .csv file that contains values with temperatures and a timestamp when the temperature was measured. What I want to do is to find time periods where the value goes done below a specific value. I wanna do it without a database, I know it is easy with mysql or something else. 
This is a private project to learn statistics with python.

#### Datastructure

```
001,"2018-8-15 08:00:00", 89
002,"2018-8-15 08:00:30", 68
003,"2018-8-15 08:01:00", 56
004,"2018-8-15 08:01:30", 55
005,"2018-8-15 08:02:00", 56
006,"2018-8-15 08:02:30", 63
```

One file contains 720 Entries for everyday.

#### What is my idea?

```
   with open('2018815') as file:
     for line in files:
       s = line.strip().split(",")

       if s[3] == "temperature":
         continue

       if int(s[3]) < 60:
         setStart()

       if int(s[3]) > 60:
         setEnd()
```

The functions `setStart` and `setEnd` are not implemented yet, because I found a mistake in my thoughts. When I ran the code and just printed the values I found out that also the periods within the periods where also defined as a period.

#### What are  my questions?

1. How to skip the periods within periods?
2. Is there a library I could use, to solve this problem more easily?

Comment: You should consider using the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: Are you able to use the pandas library? It's designed for this kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look on the `csv` module.
@roganjosh I will also have a look at pandas libraries. I think it should not be a problem to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as suggested above, pandas is the library you need, but if you want to do it with a loop on the lines you can still add a boolean to forget to add start while you are on a periode:

```
with open('2018815') as file:
     is_in_periode = False
     for line in files:
       s = line.strip().split(",")

       if s[3] == "temperature":
         continue

       if(int(s[3]) < 60 and not is_in_periode):
         setStart()
         is_in_periode = True

       if(int(s[3]) > 60 and is_in_periode):
         setEnd()
         is_in_periode = False
```